# Galois group of a polynomial-

Tags: galois-theory

We will consider the polynom $f=X^{4}+4X^{3}-4X^{2}-16X-8$. I noticed that the roots for this polynom are $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-1$, $-1-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}-1$ and $-1-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$. I would like to calculate the Galois group of the $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and explicitate the Galois correspondence. I have read the course, but I don’t understand exactly how to do this. Please tell me how could I resolve this exercise. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could resolve such exercises by reading [Conrad's notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf) on Galois groups of quartics.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $F=Gal(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.